# Why require.js keep giving me script error without reason?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, requirejs, amd

Why require.js keep giving me script error without reason?

I'm using require.js right now, I'm using amd and let typescript help me to put all compiled file into one File named 'index.js', but I'm stopped by ScriptError:

```
Uncaught Error: Script error for "main"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
at makeError (require.js:168:17)
at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1738:36)
```

In require.js docs, they said if script error happens, usually means there is a syntax error, but I'm pretty sure there's no syntax error, and the error report does not have anymore details there.

main.ts, and there's no syntax error:

```
import { greet } from "./greet";

export function mainmethod() {
    greet("Safari"); 
}
```

greet.ts:

```
export function greet(message: string): void {
    console.log("Hello, " + message);
}
```

index.html, and load modules:

```
<html>
    <canvas id = "canvas" width = "1050" height = "625" class = "MainCanvas">     </canvas>

    <script data-main = "script/index" src = "script/require.js"> </script>

    <script>
        require(["main"], function(main) { 
            main.mainmethod();
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

structure is like this:

```
index.html 
 - script
   - index.js
   - require.js
 - sourcecode
   - main.ts
   - greet.ts
 - resources
```

ps: typescript will put them into small amd module like this:

```
define("greet", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    exports.greet = void 0;
    function greet() {
        console.log("Hello, " + message);
    }
    exports.greet = greet;
}
define("main", ["require", "exports", "greet"], function (require, exports, greet_1) {
    exports.mainmethod = void 0;
    function mainmethod() {
        greet_1.greet("Safari");
    }
    exports.mainmethod = mainmethod;
}
```

Comment: What are you doing to compile *main.ts* to an AMD module? What does the resulting JavaScript look like? When the browser makes an HTTP request to `main` what is the HTTP response (use the Network tab of the browser’s developer tools to find out)?

Comment: “let typescript help me to put all compiled file into one File named 'index.js'” - In that case why aren’t you’d just loading index.js? What’s the point of throwing require.js into the mix?

Comment: @Quentin do you know require.js? It's a javascript module loader, and I'm using amd. Without require.js file, index.js cannot run, instead, I will receive 'define is not defined'

Comment: Yes, I know require.js. 99% of the questions on Stackoverflow about it don't understand the difference between AMD, CommonJS, and ES modules. You didn't include your typescript config or the output and typescript doesn't output AMD modules by default. Meanwhile most people bundling JS into a single file convert it to non-modules at the same time. That is why I checked.

Comment: When I run that code, **before** it gives the error you quoted, it errors with *Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list* on line 8 of index.js, and there is a missing `)` there. So something has gone wrong with how you created your *index.js*. Maybe it is a bug in the tool you used (I'm assuming the regular typescript compiler with a version and configuration you haven't shared with us) or maybe a problem with the configuration of it or some post processing you are doing.